# IE 11 css translate issue, flashing

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, translate

So I have a div of `.scrollable-sections` with the below styles on it, but when it comes to translating this div in IE 11 (which is done by adding a class to the parent of the `.scrollable-sections`) for some reason it flashes white when it has to translate and it's not a smooth transition.

I have trawled through other answers which is why I'm trying to force a 3d translate and adding backface-visibilty.

I'm all out of options as what else I can try to stop this glitching in ie11.

Can anyone help?

```
.scrollable-sections {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out, 
  -moz-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  will-change: "transform transition"; 
}

.viewport.js-translateX1 .scrollable-sections{
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below css help you. I have updated some css code in your css.

```
.scrollable-sections {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out, 
  -moz-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  will-change: "transform transition";
}

.viewport.js-translateX1 .scrollable-sections{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but this doesn't solve my issue as I need to translate to happen by adding another class and negatively translating by 100%.

Comment: Would be useful if you could explain why this would be a possible solution to the problem

Comment: What is this meant to be ```will-change: "transform transition";```